# \marginnote leads to paragraph indentation

Tags: indentation, marginnote

I am using the `marginnote` package in combination with `scrbook`. Normally the first paragraph after a heading is not indented. When I now use `\marginnote` at the beginning of the first paragraph it gets indented. Since I want to have the margin notes at the height of the first line of the paragraph I cannot move the `\marginnote` command to the end of the paragraph to avoid this behaviour.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\begin{document}

\chapter{test}
\marginnote{1}\blindtext

\marginnote{2}\blindtext

\chapter{test}
\blindtext\marginnote{3}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\leavevmode\marginnote{1}`. Or move the marginnote behind the first word.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you, works as expected. If you wrtite this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\leavevmode\marginnote{1}`, or move the marginnote behind the first word.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\begin{document}
\section{test a}
\marginnote{1} bllb

\section{test b}
\leavevmode\marginnote{2}blub

\section{text c}
blub\marginnote{3} blub

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This requires that there is no space between `\leavevmode\marginnote{...}` and the first word of the paragraph. For easy of use it would be preferable to separate the margin note onto one line of the file, and the start of the paragraph on another. This can be achieved by putting an `%` at the end, although I don't know why, and would prefer a solution where I wouldn't have to remember this.  (Perhaps `xspace` can be utilised?).

Comment: @oliversm % at the end of line suppress the space introduced by the linebreak. The purpose of the xspace package is to insert spaces, not to suppress them. You would need a command with \ignorespaces.

Comment: so do you see a way to neatly circumvent the need for a `%` here if you want whitespace/newlines.

Comment: @oliversm Something like `\newcommand\mymarginnote[1]{\leavevmode\marginnote{#1}\ignorespaces}` should work.

Comment: works a treat. (I had thought `\ignorespaces` was a fictitious command you were suggesting be invented, rather than one that existed!).