# Prevent marginnote from creating extra paragraph

Tags: marginnote

I use the `marginnote` package to create, well, margin notes. However, I observe some unwanted behavior when adding a note directly after a section heading, or between section headings. It seems like the command creates an empty paragraph, which is undesired, since it leads to extra whitespace or indentation.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\begin{document}

\section{Testsection}
\marginnote{Oops! Some extra whitespace.}
\subsection{Testsubsection}
But at least no indentation.

\section{Testsection2}
\subsection{Testsubsection2}
\marginnote{hi there!}Some extra indentation

\section{Testsection3}
\subsection{Testsubsection3}
Nothing \marginnote{Move along.} to see here.

\section{Testsection4}
\subsection{Testsubsection4}
\leavevmode\marginnote{Move along.}This also works.

\end{document}
```

Creates

[image: MEW output]

I have read [\marginnote leads to paragraph indentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296711/marginnote-leads-to-paragraph-indentation), so I know about the `\leavevmode` solution. However, this does not fix the first case (adding extra whitespace when between section headings).

Is there a way to define a command that will always keep `marginnote` from creating extra paragraphs, so I can use it where I want without thinking about it?

Comment: This kludge will fix it: `\section[Testsection]{Testsection\protect\marginnote{\normalsize\mdseries No extra whitespace.}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like marginnote really wants to be used mid paragraph, but this works:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\begin{document}

\section[Testsection]{Testsection\marginnote{\normalsize\normalfont
 Oops! Some extra whitespace.}}
\subsection{Testsubsection}
But at least no indentation.

\section{Testsection2}
\subsection{Testsubsection2}
%a marginpar bug \marginnote{hi there!}Some extra indentation
Some\marginnote{hi there!} extra indentation

\section{Testsection3}
\subsection{Testsubsection3}
Nothing \marginnote{Move along.} to see here.

\section{Testsection4}
\subsection{Testsubsection4}
\leavevmode\marginnote{Move along.}This also works.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I beat you by a minute with my comment, but +1 anyhow

Comment: Thanks, but I'd rather do `\newcommand{\robustmarginnote}[1]{\domagic\marginnote{#1}}`, so I can use `robustmarginnote` wherever I want. But maybe `domagic` doesn't exist, in which case your answer is of course correct.